# Javascript: How to mouseover when called out in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, onmouseover

I have a form that calls out my mouseover function. It works in Chrome, but I'm being forced to use a browser that is extremely outdated called Fresco. In Fresco it doesn't work. It doesn't swap between images when moused over. I'm just wondering if this is a best practice when using mouseover inside an input with the type of image? It's this line right here that is having trouble swapping between images when moused over:

```
echo '<br /><br /><br /><input type="image" name="button" id="button" src="category_icons/confirmorder.png" onmouseover="confirmorder2(this)" onmouseout="confirmorder(this)" /> </form> </td></tr></table>';
```

See the entire code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes']) && $_POST['chkboxes']!= "") {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
        echo '- '.$chkbox."<br />";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="'.$chkbox.'" id="chk_'.$chkbox.'" />';
    }
} 
    echo '<br /><br /><br /><input type="image" name="button" id="button" src="category_icons/confirmorder.png" onmouseover="confirmorder2(this)" onmouseout="confirmorder(this)" /> </form> </td></tr></table>';
    echo'  <table align="center" border="0" width="90%"><tr><td width="49%"></td>
                <td><a href="irohomepage.php"><img border="0" src="category_icons/cancelitem.png" onmouseover="cancelitem2(this)" onmouseout="cancelitem(this)"></a></td></tr></table>';
mysqli_close($con); //close the db connection
```

and here is the javascript function that is being used.

```
/////////////////////////////
///  CONFIRM ORDER   ///////
///////////////////////////
function confirmorder2(x) {
    "use strict";
    //x.style.height = "70px"; (makes image larger)
    //x.style.width = "237px";
    x.src = "category_icons/confirmorder2.png";
}

function confirmorder(x) {
    "use strict";
    //x.style.height = "56px"; (normal size of image)
    //x.style.width = "218px";
    x.src = "category_icons/confirmorder.png";
}
```

Like I said, it works fine in chrome, but not in this old browser called Fresco. Does this look a correct way of using onmouseover for an input type of image?

Comment: "does not work" is too ambiguous.

Comment: oh sorry. It's not swapping between images when moused over.

Comment: maybe you can reparent these images? swap the parents instead of changing `src` attributes.

Comment: According to Wikipedia this “Fresco” is a very old embedded browser, that supports JavaScript v 1.3 – so not sure if it even handles events such as mouseover already. So I’d suggest you test that first, by displaying a simply `alert` message on mouseover or something. (And do an `alert` unconditionally while loading the page as well, to see if that even works in that fossil.)

Comment: or have several images one over the other and hide all but one. and show the right one when needed. looks like this browser (which I have never heard of) does not support dynamic `src` changes.

Comment: Have you tried using css for this? I would try using the `:hover` pseudo-selector to differentiate between the two states.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. I have tried using CSS and it does not work in Fresco. onmouseover does work, though - just not when I have it in an <input>. I am going to try to reparent the images to see if that helps at all. Thanks again.